# Why is this perl regex not working?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this array.

```
my @input = ("He walk+V3SG very fast.", "He study+V3SG hard.");
```

and I want to substitute 'walk+V3SG' and 'study+V3SG' to 'walks' and 'studies'.

Below is the script I wrote. I thought this should work but for some reason it is not working.

```
    foreach my $sent(@input){
    if ($sent =~ m/\Q+V3SG/){
        if ($sent =~ m/\Q[dlr]y+V3SG/){
            $sent =~ s/\Q[dlr]y+V3SG/ies/g;
        }
        if ($sent =~ m/\Q[s|x|sh|ch|o]+V3SG/){
            $sent =~ s/\Q[s|x|sh|ch|o]+V3SG/es/g;
        }
        else {$sent =~ s/\Q+V3SG/s/g}
    }
}

foreach my $sent(@input){
    print $sent;
    print "\n";
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 2):

The `\Q` makes the rest of the regex match literally `[dlr]y+V3SG`. Moving it enables the character class to function properly:

```
s/[dlr]\Qy+V3SG/ies/g
```

or just escape the `+`:

```
s/[dlr]y\+V3SG/ies/g
```

After this change, you get, e.g:

```
He stuies hard.
```

To make sure the first letter is retained, you can use a capture or `\K` (since 5.10):

```
s/[dlr]\K\Qy+V3SG/ies/g
```

For the second regex, you're using the wrong brackets:

```
s/(s|x|sh|ch|o)\Q+V3SG/$1es/g
```

Comment: Also, they shouldn't be using an if/elsif/else at all. The sentence could contain all three forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep `\Q` just before the literal. You are placing it before whole regex, so the whole regex is considered as literal and is not interpreted.

Second thing you should use `\K` wisely to substitute. Put it just after the part you don't want to substitute. for eg: `s/[dlr]\Ky\Q+V3SG/ies/g` makes `study` `studies` and it will not remove `d` or `l` or `r` from result.

Third thing `[s|x|sh|ch|o]` will not do what you think. It will match any character in `s,x,h,|,c,o`. The correct one should be `(?:s|x|sh|ch|o)`.`(?:...)` is for non capturing group.

Finally, that shouldn't be an if/elsif/else at all. The sentence could contain all three forms.

Overall: It gives us:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = ("He walk+V3SG very fast.", "He study+V3SG hard.","He crush+V3SG hard.");

foreach (@input){
    if (m/\Q+V3SG/){
        s/[dlr]\Ky\Q+V3SG/ies/g;
        s/(?:s|x|sh|ch|o)\K\Q+V3SG/es/g;
        s/\Q+V3SG/s/g;
    }
}

foreach my $sent(@input){
    print $sent;
    print "\n";
}
```